# What do you do when a random effect is collinear with a fixed effect?

Tags: random-effects-model, multicollinearity

Say I have a dataset which has rows of observations of `Mood` (`HAPPY`/`SAD`), with info on the `user` (unique usernames), their `hometown` (a city, always the same for a given user) and their `activity` (`standing`/`sitting`/`cycling`):

| MOOD | User | Hometown | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HAPPY | Tom | New York | Standing |
| SAD | Tom | New York | Sitting |
| HAPPY | Tom | New York | Cycling |
| HAPPY | Dina | San Francisco | Standing |
| HAPPY | Dina | San Francisco | Sitting |
| HAPPY | Ellis | San Francisco | Sitting |
| HAPPY | Xiaomei | Beijing | Cycling |

I want to find out the relationship between a mood and hometown/activity. For some hometowns (e.g. Beijing) I have very few users. Therefore I want to include `user` as a random effect in my regression model, to make sure to account for any difference due to sampling the same individuals multiple times. Let's say I try to model `MOOD ~ Activity + Hometown + (1|User)`.

The problem here is that, for each user, the hometown will always be the same. My model produces errors (e.g. in R), I guess because of a collinearity problem. Is that right? I couldn't find much on what to do in these cases. I can run the model without the random effect and get neat results; however, in my field it is considered 'best practice' to use mixed-effects models.

What does one do here? Do you think my thinking on this is clear? Are there any solutions I'm missing?

Comment: What errors are you encountering trying to fit this model in R? Having a fixed effect that does not vary within units at level 2 (users, in your case) isn't usually a problem - these are commonly referred to as Level 2 variables.

Comment: Thanks! When trying `glmer(MOOD ~ Activity + Hometown + (1|User), family=binomial, data=df)`, R returns: 
`In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0743754 (tol = 0.002, component 1)`

Comment: Ok, great! There's quite a number of reasons you might encounter this (e.g., [lack of information in the binary outcome](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407426/glmer-model-failed-to-converge), [insufficient variance of the outcome within units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034261/warning-lme4-model-failed-to-converge-with-maxgrad), etc). For general guidance on addressing convergence issues, see [here](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2020-03-16-convergence/) or try `help("convergence")`. This question might also be better addressed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: One more point worth considering - if you just want to account for the fact that observations are correlated within individuals, you don't always need a multilevel model (despite their ubiquity in psychology). Fixed effects models with clustered standard errors, such as those implemented in `fixest` ([link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/index.html)) can also work well here. See [McNeish, Stapelton & Silverman (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1037/met0000078)

Comment: Thank you, those references and questions are super-helpful. FWIW I've been able to get the model to work without convergence warnings by changing the second-stage optimizer to `bobyqa`, which is great but still doesn't help me with understanding the 'problem' with my dataset. Your references have given me ways into thinking about that and I'm grateful.